# C# Last Element of List of List

Tags: c#, list

This is probably a really easy question, I want to access the last element of:

```
List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
```

So each list inside has 3 elements but how should I access the last of those lists?

Comment: Aren't you actually declaring an array of four lists-of-strings here - the lists having an arbitrary number of strings?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx):

```
string lastElement = list.Last().Last();
```

The first call will return the last `List<string>`, and the second will return the last string within that list.

Alternatively, since you know the length of the array, you can access the list directly, and do:

```
string lastElement = list[2].Last();
```

If you know, in advance, that you're always going to have 3 lists with 3 elements, you might want to consider using a multidimensional array instead:

```
string[,] matrix = new string[3,3];

// fill it in..

string last = matrix[2,2];
```

Comment: Ok, cool, but is there a way to get the index number because I want to access all three of those elements in the last list.

Comment: like list[0][lastList], list[1][lastList], list[2][lastList]

Comment: @MCH: you can do list[0].Last(), list[1].Last(), etc...  Is that what you want?

Comment: Assuming .Net 3.5+, for earlier versions of the framework, `list[3][list[3].Count - 1]` will do same.

Comment: @MCH: or, alternatively, if you want a list of all of the last elements, you can do:   list.Select(l => l.Last()).ToList();

Comment: @Will A: (should be list[2] - it's only 3 elements long)

Comment: @Reed - D'oh - good point - that's coming from a VB.Net background for you.  :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I am still very new to dot net and I am working on learning WPF, so even a few simple things have tripped me up.

Answer (score 6):

If you have `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and you want `9`, use `list.Last().Last()`.  If you want `[3,6,9]`, use `list.Select(sublist => sublist.Last())`.

Answer (score 3):

In [C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) you can use the "hat" operator (`^`) to select an element from the end of a list.

> The index from end operator `^`, which specifies that an index is
>   relative to the end of the sequence.

```
// get last item from last array
string last = list[^1][^1];
```